# How do I delegate some javascript (rendering the page) to have higher importance then other javascript (fetching data)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now my mobile web app on startup goes and talks to a few apis when it is lunched. These are intertwined with the javascript that renders the page.

When they fire at the same time page rendering gets all choppy, possibly because the rendering is using hardware acceleration, or maybe it's just normal on mobile (iphone) when running too much JS at the same time.

I want to architect the app in a way that if something like a user taking an actions to change the rendering of the page, or anything related to the UI is fired, it takes precedence over any other JS.

I want the experience to be quick and snappy even if it makes some action (talking with apis) take longer then it should.

Any idea how to achieve something like this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you doing your communication with the APIs asynchronously?

Comment: ahh, i think not :/ - I haven't done anything special to achieve this so I'm guessing no.

Comment: You may have some blocking calls then. If you can make them non-blocking then your UI will be smoother, if the API calls really are causing the UI to block.

Answer (score 1):

A given javascript thread runs to completion without interruption as Javascript is single threaded (except for Web Workers, but I don't think that's what we're talking about here).

As such, the only way to prioritize work is to create a queue of work to be done.  Do a unit of work from the queue and then decide which unit of work on the queue to do next.  If all your work to be done is in the queue, then you can decide which items should be done first when it's time to grab the next unit of work off the queue.

The smaller/shorter the units of work are, the more granular your switching between tasks can be.  If you use `setTimeout()` with a very short time between each item in the queue, that gives a chance for any UI events (like clicks or other timers) to run.

You can even fire off a bunch of ajax requests and as the responses come in, you can put the responses in the queue to be parsed/handled when there's time.

Comment: So UI events would go into the queue as well, just with higher priority? Or should they bypass it and just pause the queue until finished?

Comment: When you use setTimeout() to process your next item in the queue in a short delay (you can specify 1ms for the setTimeout(), that tells the browser that it's OK to fire any UI events.  They won't be in your queue, they will just get processed before your next queue item.

Comment: Ok, awesome. Any example out there for how to build this type of queue?

Comment: This doesn't have a queue for other work, but it's an example of running a chunk of work on a timer so the UI stays alive and so you don't get any notices from the browser about javascript running for too long: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/sMnjT/10/.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the choppy behavior is that you have a limit of how many Ajax requests can be outstanding.

You could write a javascript function / object that manages a priority queue of Ajax requests along with a callback for each. Requests are fired off in order of priority / position in the queue. New requests with high priority are executed before less important ones this way even if they may have been requested later, something like the [jquery Ajax Manager plugin](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/) + priorities added.